# How to run batch file using IronPython

Tags: c#, .net, ironpython

I have newly started working with IronPython. I have a batch file with some commands.

This file needs to be executed from IronPython. Can it be accomplished? 
I was trying to add .net reference but couldn't create object for class `Process`.  Is the approach correct?

```
  import clr
    clr.AddReference("System.Diagnostics")
    from System.Diagnostics import Process
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Diagnostics` is a namespace.

`clr.AddReference` accepts `System.Reflection.Assembly` objects and/or assembly names., e.g.:

```
clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")
```

The `Process` class is in assembly "System.dll" so you don't have to add anything.

Try this:

```
from System.Diagnostics import Process
p = Process()
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = False
p.StartInfo.FileName = 'C:\\ping.bat'
p.Start()
p.WaitForExit()
print(p.ExitCode)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the code snipet, aslo its so kind of you for taking out time to explain the process. Many thanks.